# Prevent from autoformatting after using statement

Tags: c#, formatting, autoformatting

I have this code:

```
var a = 2;
```

I type `using(...){}` above declaration 
Then I`m getting:

```
using(...)
{
}
    var a = 2;
```

visual studio adds tab to `a` declaration. I want to prevent this, how I can achieve it ?

Edit: I added braces as I don`t want to have `a` inside using.

Comment: you don't have braces or anything that ends the using like `;`

Comment: Well it's doing you a favor really. If you will not indent your code inside if\for\using\whatever blocks - it will be horrible to read.

Comment: This is the normal behavior for the formatting rules used by Visual Studio. If you want to change/experiment with them go to _TOOLS->Options->TextEditor->C#->Formatting->Indentation_ I recommend to leave them as they are unless there is a major compelling reason

Comment: The automatic brace completion in VS is a horrible misfeature, but the automatic indentation is a really good idea. Which are you objecting to?

Comment: automatic indentation is the problem

Answer (score 2):

That is because the using statement executes codes whitin the scope the variable whitin the using exists. The correct syntax for using is:

```
using (var disposeMe = new DisposeMe())
{
    // here you use the disposeMe object during its lifetime
    var a = 2;
} // here disposeMe gets disposed.
```

With regards,
John

Comment: Thats not my problem, I dont want to place `var a = 2` inside using. After I click enter I type `{}` but then I end up with:
using (var disposeMe = new DisposeMe())
{
}
    var a = 2;
Which still before declaration has 1 tab.

Comment: `var a = 2` should be **inside** the brackets if you want it there. If you omit the brackets it's the only instruction within the scope of the using, which is why VS indents it to make it clear that it is so.

Comment: If you place a {} or a ; after the using statement the var a should normally not move a tab. If it is still doing that than you should check your formatting settings for strange behaviours.

Comment: If I place a `;` its ok but when i place `{}` its still doing that. I checked all formatting settings and I have no clue which one is responsible for this strange behavior.